# how to apply DRM for iPhone Applications

Tags: iphone, drm, cydia

Sir i had developed an iphone application and released on cydia, which i seen it to be cracked in with in a day, later i came to know about the DRM , can any one please help me how to intehgrate DRM with my application

Thanks in advance

Comment: Piracy is inevitable, you cannot stop it. DRM is only going to hurt your real customers. And people use Cydia precisely to get around DRM. Just a little food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with BoltClock, its semi-pointless to have app protection in your app, I have several in Cydia. With my largest app, I do have my own implementation of "security". I wont give away my secret, but there's a way you can check against the Cydia Store API to see if your app has been legitimately purchased. Get with Jay Freeman (saurik) on how to obtain the API for this. He has written up a few guides on his backend API for Developers to check if the app has been purchased.

Alternatively, you can provide a "Free" version of your app, or a "Trial" to allow users to try your app, and if they like it, they can buy it.

A time-sensitive feature may be useful too, that is something you can look into.

Comment: If we're talking about Cydia apps. You should have posted the link to the Cydia API to save people hassle of emailing the busy Saurik. http://test.saurik.com/cydia-packagers/